# Resend behavior in MQ Light

Tags: ibm-mq, amqp, node-red

I am experimenting with assured delivery in MQ Light.

I am using Node-RED with a modified mqlight input node. I have added the following options the the subscribe() call:

```
qos: mqlight.QOS_AT_LEAST_ONCE, autoConfirm: false, ttl: (60 * 60 * 24 * 1000)
```

This requires that I call delivery.message.confirmDelivery() to acknowledge to MQ Light the receipt of the message.

The screenshot below is when the subscription from mqlight_NodeREDClient is set up with autoConfirm false, a message was received, BUT no delivery.message.confirmDelivery() was called. This was to simulate some sort of error occuring in the Node-RED flow.

I have since modified the Node-RED flow to do a confirmDelivery(), and any messages consumed by the flow now are acknowledged OK, even if Node-RED isn't running at the time of publish. The message is held by MQ Light since there is a TTL on the destination and arrives as soon as i start up Node-RED again.

However, the message in this screenshot, which has been sent once already but never confirmed, is never resent. A restart of Node-RED does not change this, the message is still pending. What are the criteria that needs to be fulfilled in order for MQ Light to retransmit a message already sent before but never confirmed by a client?
[image: Screenshot from IBM MQ Light admin UI]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hadn't restarted NodeRED I'd say that it was because MQ Light won't redeliver to a connected client because it thinks the client is still processing the message. However since you have it must be something else.

I've just tried the same basic setup (without NodeRED) and the behaviour is as you'd expect - when you reconnect the receiving client MQ Light redelivers the message and the MQ Light UI ticks it off.

The remaining things I can think of are:

1. Is it possible when that particular message was sent you had a QoS 0
   subscription?
2. What TTL are you setting on the message at the sender?
3. What destination TTL have you set on your subscribe call?

If 2. is too low, the message will have been expired from the destination regardless of the QoS of the subscriber or the value of 3.

If 3. is too low and NodeRED was stopped for long enough, the entire destination will have been expired.

Comment: The message disappeared from the UI after a few hours, unfortunately I am not logging anything on the NodeRED side yet so I am unable to tell if it actually got through or not. Now I have done some more tests and get the behaviour you see and I expect. I will do some more experimenting and see if I can reproduce it.